# WordPress: Blank screen after adding a post

Tags: wordpress

I am having problems posting on my WordPress site. When I add a post from the admin screen then the page where this post is displayed goes blank. Other pages are working fine -- only the page where that particular post is displayed goes blank.

Comment: Sounds like a PHP error. Add `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to your wp-config.php file and see if it provides more info. Post back if it does.

Comment: i tried it but it is giving warning

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /var/www/vhosts/markettrendsignal.com/httpdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/faq-builder/config.php on line 2

Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /var/www/vhosts/markettrendsignal.com/httpdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3323

Notice: add_option was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.3 with no alternative available. in /var/www/vhosts/markettrendsignal.com/httpdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.

Comment: @user1132887 I think what he means is: update the question with the error message. Don't post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a php_error because of the **faq builder** plugin.
I would suggest that you disable this plugin and install another FAQ plugin.
I suggest that you use **FAQ You** plugin, have used this on many sites without problems in the past.

If you still want to use FAQ Builder, and by looking at the error you had sent, you can still fix it to make it work by changing the plugin's code.